# Nginx 0.7.43 to proxypass a Wordpress site to Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.6

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, wordpress, proxypass

I'm trying to use an existing nginx running on port 80, to proxypass towards Apache serving a Wordpress website.

nginx section added (some commented tests left intentionally, i tried so many versions sorry if it looks wrong):

```
upstream wordpress {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    server_name media.raw-news.net;
    access_log /home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/var/log/wordpress-access.log;
    error_log /home/plumi/PLUMI/plumi.app/var/log/wordpress-error.log;

    #root /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://wordpress;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75;
        proxy_read_timeout 185;
    }

 location ~ .*\\.(php)$ {

  proxy_pass         http://wordpress;
  proxy_redirect     off;

  proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  client_max_body_size       10m;
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;

  proxy_connect_timeout      90;
  proxy_send_timeout         90;
  proxy_read_timeout         90;

  proxy_buffer_size          4k;
  proxy_buffers              4 32k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
  proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
 }

}
```

My Apache is running on port 5000 with PHP enabled (only relevant php stuff):

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

AddType text/html .php
AddHandler php5-script  .php
```

The effect right now is that:

Chrome: the Wordpress website is shown, but looks like no PHP code is executed.. i can only see the HTML part.

Firefox: browsing the Wordpress site causes redirect on 127.0.0.1 ...

Safari: It Works ! is displayed...

Strangely, on all browsers if i browse http://media.example.net/wp-admin and perform login.. i can enter the Dashboard and everything is displayed perfectly !

All images are there, PHP code gets executed... but only after logging in the Dashboard !

What am i missing here ?

I did not create any VirtualHost in Apache, it is a simple Apache 2.4 server with the Wordpress site inside the default DocumentRoot.

I cannot migrate on newer nginx version cause its running a Production website.

Migration is already planned when Plumi will officially release the 4.5.2 on Debian 8.

Is there any preferred/working configuration to properly proxypass all the Wordpress content to my Apache without having it to redirect to 127.0.0.1 for example, and properly executing PHP Code on Apache ?

Thanks !

Comment: If all the data is being sent to Apache's backend, why do you have to separate location blocks?  That only serves to do configuration code duplication...

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to set (and use) additional headers for proxying to the Apache instance, such as these:

```
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Most backends (including Apache and PHP) will work with one or more of these, as well as `$Host` (so it knows what site's being requested).

This *should* then allow for Apache's PHP to recognize the additional data and essentially say "Oh, this did NOT originate from localhost, it's actual origin is from `$remote_addr`".  (`$remote_addr` is a variable that indicates the real IP address of the real source, and the `X-Forwarded-For` works similarly.)

Comment: thanks for replying. Question edited as you are suggesting. You may also browse http://media.rawnews.net and check the actual mess i'm into.. uncommenting the "root" only causes nginx to process and log some css/js. I'd like to have everything processed by Apache, but its not happening.

Comment: @KRiSh05: edit your own question and add this data.  Also indicate in your question what you ***have*** tried - you didn't state that you tried these, therefore I could not have known.  Also, copy-pasting configs in won't help you in comments - **edit your question to add such data** instead.